# Rename multiple files in serial number in R

Tags: r

I am trying to rename files that are placed in one folder and I need this files to rename them in sequential manner. e.g if I have three file with name

a. Mastersheet.xlsx

b. Subfile.xlsx

c. Analysis.xlsx

and rename them into

a. 1.xlsx

b. 2.xlsx

c. 3.xlsx

```
files <- list.files(folder,pattern = "*.xlsx",full.names = T) 

sapply(files,FUN=function(eachPath){file.rename(from=eachPath,to=sub(pattern="*.xlsx",paste0("*.xlsx",1:34),eachPath))})
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than iterating over the names of the files, iterate over their index so you can remove the `1:34` magic value.

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx")
sapply(seq_along(files),function(x){file.rename(files[x],paste0(x,".xlsx"))})
```